# Getting data from CSV file to textView

Tags: java, android, csv, textview

I have a CSV file containing in column A 100 questions and in Column B the respective answers, what I'm trying to do is to so show in the textView the question#1 and then when you tap on the textView or a button you get answer#1,and then question#2,answer#2...NB: This is the first time I use CSV file in an android app (Novice). 
here's my code.

```
try {
            CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("medicallist.csv"));

            String [] row;
            while ((row = reader.readNext()) != null) {
                textView1.setText(row[1].toString());
            }
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I put the csv file in the raw folder and I added opencsv 2.2  jar to lib folder. 
The textView does not show any text in it. what could be the problem?

Comment: If there are 200 rows the textview will be set 200 times and only the last one will be visible. Add Log.d() statements to inspect every row. If there are no two values on every row your code will crash. So inspect row.length before you use row[1].

Comment: You cannot read a file from raw folder in this way. Please tell if CsvReader can read from an input stream. What is the reason you use a FileReader too?

Comment: Is there a full tutorial so I can get some experience to handle CSV files, this is my first time using it.

Comment: There are so many CsvReader examples in internet. Please google. You can also follow this http://www.csvreader.com/java_csv_samples.php